# C++: Converting template type char to std::string

Tags: c++, string, templates, char, type-conversion

I am new to c++ templates. I am having trouble converting a templated member object to std::string. My code below fails to print the character 'c' (on my machine it prints 'R' instead) and I can't find a way to make it work. Is there a way to do this when using char as type T?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<class T>
class A {
    public:

    T t;
    A(T t1):t{t1}{};

    std::string toString(){
        return "" + static_cast<char>(t); 
    };
};


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    A<char> a{'c'};
    cout << a.toString() <<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you plan to use other types than `char` for `T`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with

```
return "" + static_cast<char>(t);
```

is that `""` isn't a `std::string` object, it's a literal string which is a constant array of characters. As an array it will decay to a pointer to its first element, and you add `static_cast<char>(t)` to the pointer.

This new pointer will then be used as a null-terminated string to create a `std::string` object, and that usage of the invalid pointer leads to *undefined behavior*.

You can [construct a `std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) directly from a single character and return it as

```
return std::string(1, static_cast<char>(t));
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
return "" + static_cast<char>(t);
```

to

```
return std::string() + static_cast<char>(t);
```

With the original, you have a string literal treated as a pointer.

Comment: Or `return std::string(1, static_cast<char>(t));`

Comment: Thank you, this worked, although I don't really understand, why. Can you explain the difference?

Comment: @ga38xab String literal has a type of plain char array, which, when used with arithmetic, is treated as a pointer. The result of the expression is, therefore, some `const char*` value incremented by the integer value of `t`. The resulting pointer is invalid, which causes undefined behavior. You need the operator `+` to be applied to `std::string` objects instead of pointers. A compiler won't create it for you, hence you need to do this manually.

Answer (score 0):

If `std::string` is constructible from `T` you can use the following solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<class T>
class A {
    public:

    T t;
    A(T t1):t{t1}{};

    std::string toString(){
        return {t}; // <- this constructs a string from t
    };
};


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    A<char> a{'c'};
    cout << a.toString() <<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Live code [here](https://ideone.com/KJtJLL).

However this will fail if `std::string` is not constructible from `T`. In that case you can use template specialisation to handle the conversion properly.